# Has an unauthorized civilian ever tried to land on an aircraft carrier?

Tags: landing, aviation-history, aircraft-carrier

Has there ever been an attempt by a civilian 'daredevil' to land a plane on a US aircraft carrier?

I came across the [Red Square Landing](http://www.upi.com/Archives/1988/08/03/The-Soviet-Union-released-and-expelled-daredevil-West-German/8306586584000/) and coupled with [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6W9jBS9TjyQ) it made me wonder if there was ever a civilian who attempted - illegally, of course - to land a plane on a carrier?

Comment: Before landing the pilot would have to find the carrier, and to fly the distance, which could be itself a challenge. Moscow is on land.

Comment: @mins: "Moscow is on land"  _[citation needed]_

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure whether this counts, but I think the [landing of South Vietnamese Air Force Major Buang-Ly on USS midway](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=so9XRUbBGj8) using a [Cessna O-1 Bird_Dog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cessna_O-1_Bird_Dog) comes pretty close.

Though Major Buang-Ly was not a civilian, he has never seen a carrier before and the landing wasn't exactly illegal. It was permitted by [Captain Larry Chambers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lawrence_Chambers) during [Operation Frequent Wind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Frequent_Wind), who even scuttled helicopters on the deck to ensure safe landing.

The image below shows the aircraft as it comes to a stop.

[image: USS Midway]

Image from [forum.worldofwarships.com](http://forum.worldofwarships.com/index.php?/topic/2246-one-of-the-more-interesting-carrier-landings/)